# Is it appropriate to use multilevel regression models for forecasting purposes?

Tags: time-series, repeated-measures, arima, stata, multilevel-analysis

I have time series data about 10 individuals. For each of them I have 120 repeated measures over time (a monthly measure for 10 years).
I have a dependent variable (Y) and several predictors (X1, X2, ...).
I made a two-level multilevel model, with repeated measures nested within individuals.

So far I used multilevel models to see which predictors were significant in explaining Y (command -mixed- in Stata).
Now I would like to use the final model for forecasting purposes.

- Is it appropriate to use multilevel models for forecasting purposes?
- Can you point me to a tutorial in Stata to learn how to do that? And to understand the connected diagnostics?
- Can you also point me to some literature that supports the use of multilevel regression models for forecasting purposes?
- Alternatively, which other approach would you recommend? ARIMAX? or others?

Cross posted on [Statalist](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1428396-is-it-appropriate-to-use-multilevel-regression-models-for-forecasting-purposes)

Comment: Multilevel models are used for clustered data; like students in a school, or teeth in a mouth. how would you generate a set of predictions for a newly adopted cluster? How might you update your prediction algorithm with new data?

Comment: These are some of the questions for which I'm looking for an answer. Or, which is the alternative? A new cluster in my case would mean a new individual, which now I don't need as I'm making my forecast for the same 10 individuals with no plans of adding new ones.

Comment: Multilevel models are also entirely appropriate for use with repeated measures collected over time within the same individuals (i.e., the clustering unit IS the individual). You could absolutely use these models to predict future outcomes for each of your ten cases. But, if change over time is not easily captured within a regression modeling framework, you want to explore other approaches.

Comment: Thanks @Matt. How do I see if change over time is captured? What should I check? So far I included dummy variables to account for seasonal trends.

Comment: So really this comes down to exploratory data analysis. Do you see in your data a global function you could specify in a linear or generalized linear mdoel? The most obvious is a linear pattern of change fitting your ten cases well. Although you may see curvilinear, or even periodic features to your timeseries data, some of which can still be modeled in a multilevel framework. Others of which may be more appropriately forecasted in other models.